# Celery in Django: celery beat doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, celery, django-celery

settings.py:

```
#CELERY
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'  # URL для Redis брокера
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'  # URL для Redis бэкенда результатов


# Настройки для Celery Beat (периодические задачи)
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'execute_daily_task': {
        'task': 'your_app.tasks.execute_daily_task',  # Путь к вашей задаче
        'schedule': crontab(minute=47, hour=18),  # Запускать в полночь каждый день
    },
}
```

root **init**.py:

```
# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

celery.py in root directory:

```
# celery.py

from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# Установка переменной окружения DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE для работы с Django
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'sites.settings')

# Создание экземпляра Celery
app = Celery('sites')

# Загрузка конфигурации Celery из настроек Django
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Автоматическое обнаружение и регистрация задач в приложениях Django
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

tasks.py in users app:

```
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from datetime import date
from .models import Company

@shared_task
def execute_daily_task():
    print('celery is working')
```

ran beat, worker, django-runserver in 3 powershells:

```
celery -A sites worker --loglevel=info

 -------------- celery@LAPTOP-2554OM7H v5.3.3 (emerald-rush)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0 2023-09-01 18:45:29
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         sites:0x26e0ad706d0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . users.tasks.execute_daily_task

[2023-09-01 18:45:29,398: WARNING/MainProcess] C:\Users\hp\desktop\TechnicalSupport\venv\Lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py:507: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
  warnings.warn(

[2023-09-01 18:45:30,133: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379//
[2023-09-01 18:45:30,135: WARNING/MainProcess] C:\Users\hp\desktop\TechnicalSupport\venv\Lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py:507: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
  warnings.warn(

[2023-09-01 18:45:30,228: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2023-09-01 18:45:30,398: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 19332 calling self.run()
[2023-09-01 18:45:30,457: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 18856 calling self.run()
[2023-09-01 18:45:30,508: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 17284 calling self.run()
[2023-09-01 18:45:30,578: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 19352 calling self.run()
[2023-09-01 18:45:31,495: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2023-09-01 18:45:32,769: INFO/MainProcess] celery@LAPTOP-2554OM7H ready.
```

```
 celery -A sites beat --loglevel=info
celery beat v5.3.3 (emerald-rush) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2023-09-01 18:45:38
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://localhost:6379//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
[2023-09-01 18:45:38,459: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
(venv) PS C:\Users\hp\desktop\TechnicalSupport\sites> celery -A sites beat --loglevel=info
celery beat v5.3.3 (emerald-rush) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2023-09-01 18:46:05
Configuration ->
    . broker -> redis://localhost:6379//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
[2023-09-01 18:46:05,258: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
```

```
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\TechnicalSupport\sites\sites\settings.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 01, 2023 - 18:46:01
Django version 4.2.1, using settings 'sites.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

I'm expecting print message to work in 18:47 of my computer time every day. Now it doesn't work and beat is always in "Starting..." state in a console (don't know, if it's normal)